# Mockup strategy for Responsive Web Design (from a programmer point of view)

Tags: web-development, responsive-design, mockups

When making mockups for *Responsive Web Design* projects, should I separate them by **Page** or by **Screen Size**? Which one would be more helpful when I start writing the source code?

What are the pros and cons of the following:

- Page based: All the home page mockups in all different screen sizes
- Screen-size based: All the pages for width <= 960px

I'm using [Balsamiq Mockups](http://balsamiq.com/products/mockups/) to make mockups and I prefer to store all related mockups in a file like `homepage, login` or `960px, 768px`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Screen-size is an overall approach that can covers a lot of device display of today market.
But Page based approach allows to create a perfect application designed for each mobile device screen.

Today the recommended approach is Screen-size based because the amount of devise increase every day with different screen size and characteristics.

Comment: that make sense somehow ... hmm, we usually don't design for each screen-size, but for some form of most-popular or standard screen-sizes, right? ... I really need to think about that. Thanks anyways for the input! :)